# Need brackets in commands when using methods with any operation

Tags: php

I've found out that when I'm working with methods, in some situations, I need to use brackets.

The next command does not work:

```
if(file_exists(str_replace($imagen->getNumeroImagen()+1.'.'.$imagen->getFormato(),$imagen->getNumeroImagen()-5.'.'.$imagen->getFormato(),$imagen->getRuta())))
```

I need to use brackets between "$imagen->getNumeroImagen()+1" and "$imagen->getNumeroImagen()-5".

```
if(file_exists(str_replace(($imagen->getNumeroImagen()+1).'.'.$imagen->getFormato(),($imagen->getNumeroImagen()-5).'.'.$imagen->getFormato(),$imagen->getRuta())))
```

Why are needed here?

Comment: The dot operator has the same precedence as `+` and `-`.

Comment: You are not listing arguements with `,`

Comment: And what would you adding here? $imagen->getNumeroImagen()+1.'.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell your code what to do first

First you want to do

```
$imagen->getNumeroImagen()+1
```

Then you want to concatenate.

Otherwise the . operator is thrown into the mix

Comment: Is it because it is a function? Because the brackets wouldn't be needed if use variables.